# show skype as option when dialing from android application

Tags: android, skype

I want to show skype in the dialing option list as [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpOis.png) when dialing from my application. Where I need to change?

Sorry if the question is too naive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Skype application, but I assume it is taking advantage of Android's Intent system: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Have you tried something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+123456789"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It is making call obviously. but I am not sure if Skype will be on that list. I am on emulator so I can't setup & test skype.

Comment: You could try running something like this in the emulator:
http://phandroid.com/2010/10/07/skype-gets-hacked-for-3g-calling-get-the-apk-now/ (though I don't know if that version is new enough to have the feature you want). Try searching for a Skype apk on Google if it isn't

Comment: When I do this on my stock Nexus 4 I don't get Skype, only the dialer is triggered. If on the other hand I use android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED as the intent, then I get Skype (and Lync) but not the default dialer.