# how to show activity chooser menu when dialing in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, skype

I am trying to show activity chooser menu when dialing a number. Following code works for me when sending an email (from real phone,doesn't work in emulator):

```
        /* Create the Intent */
    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    /* Fill it with Data */
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"to@email.com"});
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text");

    /* Send it off to the Activity-Chooser */
    this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

But when I change the code as:

```
        Intent call = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNo));
    this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(call, "Hello there..."));
```

No activity chooser menu is shown, just straight dial. I also want to list skype in that menu. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone else answered in one of your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318035/show-skype-as-option-when-dialing-from-android-application), you really do need to read up on [Intents and Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html). I'll give you a quick explanation though. An `Intent` is a type of message that Android applications can register to handle. If Skype is not installed, then it won't be able to register for that `Intent` and so won't show up in that menu. If it *is* installed and still doesn't show up, that means it's not registered for that `Intent`. I don't know the Android Skype app, but judging from the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpOis.png) you linked in the other question, it seems that it does register for that `Intent` and will show up when installed.

Comment: that is exactly my point of view. but as I know skype is a caller application which should obviously handle a call. Is there any way to forcefully register an application for an intent?

Comment: or how can I know which intent a 3rd party application handles?

Comment: Well, you wouldn't want Skype to be on that menu if the person doesn't have Skype installed right? And if it *is* installed, then Skype would register for the intent itself. Unless you're saying that Skype is installed and you still don't see it on that menu?

Comment: Yes skype is installed and I don't see it on that menu, even the menu! Can you please suggest me a similar app for 2.2, so that I can test?

Comment: It seems that Skype simply doesn't register for that intent. You'll have to dig into the internals of how the Skype app works if you want to deal with this. I don't think Skype has documentation for this so you'll have to do it manually. While looking at LogCat, open up Skype and start a call. See what intents are called. You'll have to find out how these work, what data is passed, etc. You'll be working with an undocumented API, so Skype can break your app with an update at any time.

Comment: my mistake, skype 1.0.0.659 shows appropriately. perviously that skype was a beta version!